# Count number of rows for each printed table

Tags: javascript, html

I need your assistant in getting the total number of rows for each printed table in my html to be shown at the top of it.

I am having multiple tables in the html which their id is unique "detailsTable". Each table has different number of rows. I search for a script to print the total number of rows and I found the below script:

```
function count()
{
var rows = document.getElementById("detailsTable").getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
alert(rows); 
}
```

and in the body tag, I placed:

```
<body onload="count()">
```

When I ran the page, it shows an alert for the first table which it has 22 records and the script ignores the below tables.

So, can you please help me to modify the above code and to display the alert for the other tables.

Comment: Ids must be unique. So, if all the tables have the same Id you're going to have to change that. maybe use a class and [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) or [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) instead (note they will return an array of elements)

Comment: If more than one table has the id "detailsTable" then it is **not** unique :), just saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id should be unique for every html element.

You can use class instead, and then:

```
function count()
{
var tables = document.getElementsByClassName("detailsTable");
var rows;
for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
  rows = tables[i].rows.length;
  alert(rows); 
}
}
```

Comment: The table has an existing class="tablesorter" and I replaced the detailsTable in the above code with the tablesorter and it didn't work

Comment: There is a [*table.rows*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/tabular-data.html#dom-table-rows) collection, no need for *getElementsByTagName*.

Comment: Should I remove the var rows = tables[i].getElementsByTagName("tr").length; line?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count table rows with id = "detailsTable"

```
var rowCount = $('#detailsTable tr').length;
```

If you want to find it for every table, it would look something like:

```
$('.details').each(function(index) {
   var rowCount = this.rows.length;
})
```

Comment: Assuming you can use jQuery.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work function count()
{
var rowCount = $('#detailsTable tr').length;
$('.detailsTable').each(function(index) {
   var rowCount = this.rows.length;
   alert(rowcount);
})

}